# Can files added to gitignore be used if the repo has been pulled or cloned?

Tags: json, git, github, gitignore

I have some json files for a mock server I use for automation tests I have created. I don't want to commit those json files because they have tokens in them that I don't want to push to my repo. I know I can use gitignore to not track those json files but I need for anyone who pulls or clones my repo to be able to run my automation tests and those tests need those json files. If someone pulls or clones my repo will they still be able to run my tests even if I have the files in gitignore?

Comment: You stated you have some files that you don't want others to see. You also stated you want others to have the files on their machine. That's a contradiction, isn't it?

Comment: A hint here might be to pull those tokens out of the files, and put them in a file that is ignored, or outside of the repo, and thus not tracked.

Comment: No need to be rude. I just wasn't sure how it worked

Comment: Oh! I apologize if it seemed rude; I certainly didn't intend it that way. Just a factual statement, I think. (?) Anyway- my second comment is one way to handle it, if you can read in the tokens from another file.

Comment: I guess I took it the wrong way. I apologize for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, anything in gitignore is simply ignored and no one will ever hear about them [gitignore in GIT documents](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
I would suggest using .env for the tokens [As shown here](https://consensys.net/blog/developers/how-to-avoid-uploading-your-private-key-to-github-approaches-to-prevent-making-your-secrets-public/)